# Incremental load in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to load new records from a log file (with columns in [] brackets) using Logstash. The file name and location will be constant but new records will be appended to the bottom of file. Logstash needs to continuously monitor and load new records. Thanks a lot for your help!

Example: FILE1.log

```
[2016-12-08T18:08:22,779][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [58Z8vjS] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-12-08T18:08:22,788][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [58Z8vjS] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2016-12-08T18:08:26,093][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [58Z8vjS] new_master {58Z8vjS}{58Z8vjS8TviDSa9V1Yg-5w}{u4upnHFyS7GQ6UcxQb3Rvw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2016-12-08T18:08:26,241][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [58Z8vjS] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-12-08T18:08:26,241][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [58Z8vjS] started
[2016-12-08T18:08:27,486][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [58Z8vjS] recovered [10] indices into cluster_state
```

Comment: You are pretty much describing the default behavior of the `file` input. If you haven't tried that, please do. If you have, is there something about it that didn't work for you?

Comment: I agree with the above comment. If the file is not on same machine as your logstash instance, you can use a shipper like python-beaver or filebeat, which are made for such an use case.